# Spread operator not working with module function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've this function in a module for to load a files as base64 and its attributes:

```js
function getFiles(obj, type) {
  let destinazione = type;
  let files = obj.files;
  let imagesDocs = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(ev) {
      let result = this.result;
      let f = {
        name: file.name,
        size: file.size,
        type: file.type,
        data: result
      };
      imagesDocs.push(f);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
  return imagesDocs;
}

export default getFiles;
```

In another module, I import fileArray module and use it as:

```js
const resultArray = getFiles(e.target, type);
let newArray = [...resultArray];
console.log(newArray);
```

console.log show me an empty array, while resultArray contain more objects.

I tried too with:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let newnumbers = [...numbers];
```

and work fine.

Why?

**Update:**

Using the Anson Miu's code I resolved.
The "files" variable, being filelist type must be converted to array type. I did it with [...files].

Thanks to all.

Comment: You export fileArray but there is no array called fileArray in that file?

Comment: It's because none of the stuff in reader.onload has happened at the point that you try to log newArray.

Comment: @PixAff I corrected it

Comment: @James console.log(resultArray) show mi this: []
0: {name: "2257081.jpg", size: 77830, type: "image/jpeg", data: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: console.log is kind of async, though, so you don't see the data as it was when the console.log happened.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: @James thanks. Then I must to manage the asynchronius file loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `reader.onload` is an asynchronous process.

What happens is that you loop through all the files, then you pass the empty result (`imagesDocs`) back, and then sometime later populate `imagesDocs`.

you need to handle the process asynchronously, using callback, async/await and/or promises.

Comment: The function return a loaded array.

Comment: @Kraken this is definitely the problem.

Comment: @James Ok, I undestood now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`reader.onload` is an asynchronous callback, so it is possible that the `imageDocs` array is not populated when you return from your `getFiles` function.

I suggest to extract the logic for reading a file into a separate function that returns a Promise:

```js
function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(ev) {
      const result = this.result;
      resolve({
        name: file.name,
        size: file.size,
        type: file.type,
        data: result,
      });
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

Then update `getFiles` to be an asynchronous function that maps the files to Promises and returns a Promise that resolves to the `imageDocs`:

```js
async function getFiles(obj, type) {
  const destinazione = type;
  const files = obj.files;
  const imageDocs = await Promise.all(files.map(readFile));
  return imageDocs;
}
```

Comment: It return: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: files.map is not a function"

Comment: From your OP it seems that `files` is iterable - you can use `Array.from(files)` to convert it into an array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to

```
export default getFiles;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've removed the variable name. I've editet the code. It not work